# Does Java 7 load .ZIP file into memory?

Tags: java, zip

When call `new ZipFile(myZip)`, does Java 7 loads the whole zip file into memory? Or it only loads the entry on demand? I had a look at the implementation, but the `open` method is a native method.

Comment: One way to test it is to read each entry in turn of a lot of small entries in a big Zip.  I'll bet the answer is 'no'.

Comment: From looking at the source code (and based on how the API works) - No.  The API will load each entry (index) as requested (it may cache them, but that's an implementation issue), but the actually data isn't loaded until you open an `InputStream` to an entry and actually read it...

Comment: Zip files have a "directory" and content scan wouldn't allocate memory for anything other than a list of file names with paths and file sizes plus a few bits of other metadata. During decompression they decompress a file to memory or to disk for you by your request.